# Specific to Cryptokitties -- Trying to learn how SaleClockAuction works

Tags: solidity, cryptokitties, auctions

I'm trying to understand, how the actual process of putting something up for **auction** works and also how does `web3` interact with this auction.

Here are my findings till now:

1. I think that `SaleClockAuction.sol` has to be deployed with `_nftAddress` and `cut`.
2. What is `nftAddress`? Is it an address of another contract (`ERC721` contract, maybe?) or the users **current account address**?
3. Ok, once deployed, the address of `SaleClockAuction.sol` has to be copied and this address in turn has to be called from `KittyCore.sol` in order to un pause the contract.
4. Now, how is the process of  calling functions that puts up something for auction or bids on an auction work?  I see that the `KittyCore` exposes `createAuction` but not `bid`. Do users directly interact with the `external` functions of the deployed `SaleClockAuction` contract?

**Where I am stuck with**

Either calling `createAuction` from `KittyCore.sol` or `createAuction` and `bid` from `SaleClockAuction.sol` is throwing an error for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Correct. The `cut` can be zero, but must be specified. The `_nftAddress` must point to a contract that implements ERC-721 (at least the draft that was in place at the time we published CK).
2. See above.
3. The deployment order is:

   1. Deploy the core contract.
   2. Deploy the auction contract passing the core contract address as `_nftAddress`.
   3. Call the `setSaleAuctionAddress` on the core contract, so it has a reference back to the auction contract. *This is almost certainly the step you are missing.*
4. The original goal was that KittyCore wouldn't need to be involved in auctions at all, but that required two transactions (an approve call, and then a call to start the auction), and we didn't want to make our users do that all the time. To avoid this, we have the creation of a sale auction handled by the core contract. Bidding happens by calling the auction contract directly, as you suggest.

Comment: Woot!
Thanks for the response! Please keep a tab on this thread. I have a few more questions.

Comment: And how do you manage update of contract? The comments on top of the update function reads, that you have to follow instructions from README.md file. Will you open source that file?